# Dovecot zlib compressed mail

Tags: dovecot, roundcube

I'm doing migration of existing mails from old mail server to a now one. Some of the emails are compressed with zlib. At the file **10-mail.conf** in old server there is setting for zlib plugin:

> mail_plugins = zlib

I tried with same setting on new mail server as well as changing the setting to

> mail_plugins = $mail_plugins zlib

Restarted dovecot several times. The message appears in **roundcube** inbox but the content cannot be displayed. I found few tutorials and they point to same settings that I already did. Is there another configuration that I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you believe that the syntax used is valid?

Comment: Which syntax precisely? Thanks.